# Predict Suburb Volume from State Volume

Tags: regression, machine-learning, classification

I'm trying to figure out the best statistical / machine learning model for this problem.

I want to predict monthly volume of something at the suburb level.

At the end of each year, the annual volume is published by suburb. At the end of each month, the monthly volume is published by state.

The primary predictor of volume will be population size and perhaps age of population.

Originally, my idea was a simple linear regression based on the suburb population and the known volume per capita at the state level, which would give me the predictions for monthly suburb volume. However, if I were to add up all those suburb predictions, it's unlikely that they will equal the known state total. This tells me that my model is wrong.

Perhaps this is a classification problem, and what I'm trying to do is allocate the known state volume to each suburb. But there are hundreds of suburbs per state which I'm guessing is not feasible.

Any help you could give me that would point me down the right road / model would be greatly appreciated.

Regards
Sean